# Axios instance in React hook "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

The axios instance is not yet ready upon render as I get the error "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined", BUT the branches are loaded, so apparently next attempt succeeds.

The axios instance in `hooks.js`:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {useKeycloak} from '@react-keycloak/web';
import {BASE_URL} from '../constants.js';

export const useAxios = () => {
    const {keycloak, initialized} = useKeycloak();
    const [axiosInstance, setAxiosInstance] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: BASE_URL,
            headers: {
                Authorization: initialized ? `Bearer ${keycloak.token}` : undefined,
            },
        });

        setAxiosInstance({instance});

        return () => {
            setAxiosInstance({});
        }
    }, [keycloak, initialized, keycloak.token]);

    return axiosInstance.instance;
};
```

The error is in the 'Registration' component:

```
import {useAxios} from "../utilities/hooks";

const Registration = () => {
    const {initialized} = useKeycloak();
    const axiosInstance = useAxios();
    const [branches, setBranches] = useState({});

    const loadBranches = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axiosInstance.get('/branch');
            setBranches(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error when loading branches: ${error.message}`, error);
        }
    }, [axiosInstance]);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadBranches();
    }, [loadBranches]);

...
```

I first had things working without errors with a similar `fetch` function, so it seems the axios instance (which is imported) is the culprit. I find it also a bit strange that I can not do:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        loadBranches();
    }, []);
```

as then I get `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'loadBranches'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2430 printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:138 handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:143 push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:210`

this was not the case when using fetch..., and to simulate a 'when mounted' you'd normally use [].

How can I ensure `axiosInstance` exists at mount?

Comment: it's async, means u need to wait. You simply check if axiosInstance is ready before using it.

Comment: seem that the useEffect cleanup function is being called though it's being removed ! 
one question why using clean up function ?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Ok, how do i do that?

Comment: @SadhilSpring When I comment out the cleanup function in `useAxios` problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it simpler :

```
const Registration = () => {
    const axiosInstance = useAxios();
    const [branches, setBranches] = useState({});

    const loadBranches = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
              const response = await axiosInstance.get('/branch');
              setBranches(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error when loading branches: ${error.message}`, error);
        }
    }, [axiosInstance]);

    useEffect(() => {
           axiosInstance && loadBranches(); // <== here
    }, [loadBranches, axiosInstance]);
```

It will only invoke the loadBranches function when the axiosInstance is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it wait till `axiosInstance` is defined, e.g. as follows:

```
const Registration = () => {
    const axiosInstance = useAxios();
    const [branches, setBranches] = useState({});
    const [axiosReady, setAxiosReady] = useState(false);

    const loadBranches = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            if (axiosReady) {
                const response = await axiosInstance.get('/branch');
                setBranches(response.data);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error when loading branches: ${error.message}`, error);
        }
    }, [axiosReady, axiosInstance]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (axiosInstance) {
            setAxiosReady(true);
        }
    }, [axiosInstance]);

    useEffect(() => {
            loadBranches();
        }, [loadBranches]
    );

...
```

The component loads fine without the error now and properly triggers axios.

Comment: Would it also be possible to 'make it wait' within the `hooks.js` by making it a promise or something...?! That would save monitoring the state wherever it is used.